# How to set a GstPlayer pipeline?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtsp

I have constructed a custom GStreamer pipeline that I will use to play RTSP streams. At the same time I'd like to create a new `GstPlayer` to use this pipeline. The problem is that there isn't a way that I can see to set a `GstPlayer`'s pipeline (the only related method is [`gst_player_get_pipeline()`](https://coaxion.net/~slomo/gst-player/docs/gst-player-gstplayer.html#gst-player-get-pipeline). I don't understand how there is no way to customize a pipeline for a GstPlayer. This seems like basic functionality, so I must be missing something.

My pipeline:

```
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *filter, *sink;

  // Create pipeline elements
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("vdi-pipeline");
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "vdi-source");
  filter = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin", "vdi-filter");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("appsink", "vdi-sink");
  if (!source || !filter || !sink)
  {
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Error", "A GstElement could not be created. Exiting.");
    return;
  }

  // Add elements to pipeline
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, filter, sink, NULL);

  // Link elements together
  if (!gst_element_link_many (source, filter, sink, NULL)) {
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Warning", "Failed to link elements!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can play rtsp via GstPlayer out of the box.. why do you want custom pipeline? 
The player is using playbin which accept any kind of url.. and it will create pipeline dynamically according to what is being played..

What about patching the player itself, if you really cannot use playbin? I dont think it is intended for custom pipelines.. but you can hack it [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/gst-libs/gst/player/gstplayer.c?h=1.8#n2366).

You will then have hook the newpads and other callback on the rtspsrc instead of playbin.. and other stuff - I guess you do not want this.

The other way is - when the playbin constructs pipeline it uses rtspsrc inside - you can get this element from pipeline object and change some parameters.. but be carefull as changing parameters during playback is very tricky..

UPDATE:

Hm I think I overlook the appsink somehow.. well I think you can set playbin property [audio-sink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--audio-sink) or video-sink to override it to use appsink.

But still you will have to somehow get the playbin element out of GstPlayer or set the playbin parameter upon initialization (I dont know how) - in this case I would ask on IRC (freenode, #gstreamer) if you are going the right direction.

Maybe better way would be to create your own application using decodebin and or even [playbin](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Playback+tutorial+1%3A+Playbin2+usage) and pass there the appsink element.. why do you want to use GstPlayer if you are not playing but processing buffers?

HTH

Comment: I should have specified the reason I need a custom pipeline in the question. I'm trying to retrieve a frame from the live stream to process elsewhere. I believe I need to use an `appsink` element as a sink in the pipeline, then while video is playing call `gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink)` to get the current frame which I can then process how I want (in my case I just want to create a bitmap).